# Prison Architect version specific tags

Tags: discussion, tags, game-versions

I would like to see alpha-version specific tags used on [Prison Architect questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prison-architect) to help me filter out questions/problems that have most likely been fixed in an update.

New releases are fairly frequent so it would also remove the need to ask the OP which version they are running before being able to say it's been fixed in a later release or trying to reproduce the problem.

I'm less concerned with the platform (PA is available on Mac, PC, Linux and Steam) as all bugs seem to manifest in the same way irrespective of platform.

The format for other games' major versions appears to be `[game-name-n]` where `n` is the version. So I'd like to see `[prison-architect-a16]` for Alpha-16 which is currently the most recent release.

Comment: That sounds about like how Minecraft works, and it doesn't have version specific tags. Just put a little extra effort into helping them. It won't hurt you.

Comment: I'm interested to know why people down vote a question tagged [discussion] without leaving a comment. I thought having a discussion was to get people's opinions, not just down votes?

Comment: It's likely they feel there is nothing left to discuss and are just showing their opinion of your proposed tagging.

Comment: @Tony On Meta sides of a given Stack, votes are basically notes of approval or disapproval of a given suggestion/discussion/etc. Any downvote should be taken as a tacit "I disagree with your thesis" (and no, there should be no expectation to back that up).

Comment: @RilgonArcsinh - Thanks for your comment but that's not how the [Help](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) describes the use of voting. It says `Reputation is a rough measurement of how much the community trusts you` and [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it says '...voting voting down a post signals the opposite: that the post contains wrong information, is poorly researched, or fails to communicate information`.

Comment: @RilgonArcsinh - I appreciate there is no directive requiring a comment when down voting, I just think it's polite. And what's the use of the [discussion] tag if nobody contributes to the discussion? ;)

Comment: @Tony Both of those FAQs are for the primary side of the Stack (and are accurate), *not* for Meta.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no need for this. Old questions - and more importantly: answers - should be *updated* over time, if they are no longer valid. That's the beauty of our system, we can change the data to apply to the current state of affairs.

Generally speaking, one would only play the *most recent* version, not any previous ones. As such, there is usually no need to keep the data for old versions around separately.

Comment: Also: If there's a need to keep old and new data, we can always keep *multiple answers, or sections in answers* for the different versions.

Comment: Couldn't have said it better myself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it makes perfect sense. I guess I was being lazy in my searches :)

Answer (score 2):

The situation seems similar to that of Minecraft a while ago and I think version tags are unnecessary. If a question is about a bug or something unexplained happening in the game, the question should specify the version. If it doesn't, comment and ask for it.

If it's a bug specific to certain version, but has been fixed since, you should say that updating the game will fix it and possibly keep a workaround in the answer as well for the older version.